# How to access two-dimensional list that is a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a `dict` (`RefGenomesDict`) in which the keys are accession numbers (`string`) and the values are two-dimensional lists of gene properties. When I check RefGenomesDict to see that it does contain the expected annonymous two-dimensional list by using

```
for key in RefGenomesDict.keys():
    print(str(key)+ "\t" + str(RefGenomesDict[key]))
```

the expected contents are printed for each key.

When I try to assign the list to a new variable by using

```
InfoList = copy.deepcopy(RefGenomesDict[AccNum])
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.
```

How can I get access to the values in the two dimensional list?

Comment: `AccNum` is a list. So, use an int, or whatever the key actually is?

Comment: Could you show us your dictionary?

Comment: Why the double lookups? You can do `for key,value in somedict.items()` (iteritems in python 2).

Comment: The problem lay with a stupid typo bug earlier in the script.  My apologies to all for taking your time.

Answer (score 3):

Python dictionaries do not support mutable objects as keys in general because they are not hashable. Mutable types include, `dict`, `set`, and *`list`*.

```
In [386]: {[1, 2] : 123}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-386-3ba6ff881f9f> in <module>()
----> 1 {[1, 2] : 123}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

If you're trying to access a dictionary by key and getting this error, you're definitely using an invalid key to index. `AccNum`, by the looks of the error, is a list.

You should be able to iterate over the keys in a loop and assign the value to `InfoList`, like this:

```
for key in RefGenomesDict:
    InfoList = copy.deepcopy(RefGenomesDict[key])
```

This is fine if you're trying to make changes to `InfoList` you don't want reflecting in the original. If this isn't the case, you might want to drop the `deepcopy` call.